# Kotlin comparable with operators to check two objects are equal

Tags: java, kotlin

I don't understand about comparable two instance in Kotlin.
We can compare objects with <, >, <=, >= using implementation compareTo method, but if we use ==, equals will be used implicitly. How can I use compareTo method to check that the two objects are equal.

Comment: `a.compareTo(b) == 0`? But Comparable, in general, should be consistent with equals, so two equal object (in terms of equals) should be equal (in terms of compareTo), and vice-versa

Comment: What @JBNizet said - otherwise things like `TreeSet` begin to behave rather strangely.